# Military presence public order bonus

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Does anyone have any information about the public order bonus a city gets for having a general with units stationed in it?  For the life of me, I haven't been able to find any real info about how the bonus is calculated.

Comment: The bonus depends on the size of your army, i.e. the number of men in your army.

Comment: Do you know if the quality of unit is taken into account?

Comment: In *Rome Total War* it wasn't, so a unit of 240 peasants had the same bonus as two units of 120 legionaries. I'm not too sure about *Total War Rome 2* though, sorry.

Comment: Also note that it shared across each province.